# Update React component based on global variable updated by another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a global variable called `global.language`. In my `CustomHeader` component, I have a `Button` that toggles the language global variable. What I want is to update all my screen components to reflect the language change.

I don't know if the best way to go is to get a reference to the Screens or to use an event library or if there are React friendly ways of doing this.

My CustomHeader.js looks like this:

```
export default class CustomHeader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.toggleLanguage = this.toggleLanguage.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onPress={ this.toggleLanguage } title="Language" accessibilityLabel="Toggle language" />
        );
    }

    toggleLanguage() {
        if (global.language == "PT")      global.language = "EN";
        else if (global.language == "EN") global.language = "PT"; 
    }
}
```

My Screen.js renders numerous components called `Event`. This is what my Event.js looks like:

```
export default class Event extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <Text>{Event.getTitle(this.props.data)}</Text>
            </Card>
        );
    }

    static getTitle(data) {
        if (global.language === "PT")      return data.title;
        else if (global.language === "EN") return data.title_english;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using Redux if you're not too far into your project. It will do exactly this for you. Otherwise you'll have to have your components implement a listener for changes in the global.

Comment: I believe Context API will help you

Comment: @helper I am too far into the project, so I cannot start using Redux. It's also sprint based so I need this done quick and with little project changes...

Comment: @skyboyer From what I see, the Context API could work for me. Would you please elaborate a small example?

Comment: First of all, you can never be "too deep in the project" for adding a store to your app. Second, you could to go the old fashion way by registering the "Event" components to a server event that will cause them to re-sample the global value, and bind this value to the "Event-component" state, so it will re-render itself only if there is an actual difference between states.

Comment: Global variables like this are not recommended. One way to handle this is declare this variable in parent and pass a callback function (which changes this variable) as property and call that function on toggle in child.
Now, from parent, this variable can be passed to any component as required and it will be available across those components

Answer (score 1):

[Live sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wqqp64vq9l)

In details.
`React.createContext` we can just export to reuse. But this would be just "generic" context. Better encapsulate data and methods we need into custom container element and HOC:

```
import React from "react";

const context = React.createContext();
export class I18N extends React.Component {
  state = {
    language: "en"
  };

  setLanguage = language => {
    this.setState({ language });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <context.Provider
        value={{ language: this.state.language, setLanguage: this.setLanguage }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </context.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export function withI18n(Component) {
  return props => (
    <context.Consumer>
      {i18nContext => <Component {...props} i18n={i18nContext} />}
    </context.Consumer>
  );
}
```

`<I18N>` is provider that will typically go just once on the topmost level.
And with HOC `withI18n` we are going to wrap every element that need access to our language value or ability to update this value.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { I18N, withI18n } from "./i18n";

const Header = withI18n(function({i18n}) {
  const setLang = ({ target: { value } }) => i18n.setLanguage(value);
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="radio" value="en" checked={i18n.language === "en"} onChange={setLang} /> English
      <input type="radio" value="fr" checked={i18n.language === "fr"} onChange={setLang} /> French
      <input type="radio" value="es" checked={i18n.language === "es"} onChange={setLang} /> Spanish
    </div>
  );
});

const Body = withI18n(function(props) {
  return <div>Current language is {props.i18n.language}</div>;
});

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<I18N>
  <Header />
  <Body />
</I18N>, rootElement);
```

And finally good article with some additional details: https://itnext.io/combining-hocs-with-the-new-reacts-context-api-9d3617dccf0b